# What is the correct ratio to make self-rising flour?

Tags: baking, substitutions, flour, baking-powder, rising

I have a recipe that I've used a couple of times that asks for self-rising flour. Unfortunately, I only have regular AP flour where I am right now.

I know self-rising flour is a mixture of AP flour and baking powder, but I don't know the ratio.

I've found some estimations online, but they vary quite a bit.

How much baking powder do I need for 1 kg of AP flour?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For 1 cup self-raising flour, add 1½ tsp baking powder+ ¼ tsp salt to 1 cup all purpose flour. (http://www.joyofbaking.com/IngredientSubstitution.html)

*Edit*: Calculation added by Sebbidychef:

According to http://www.jsward.com/cooking/conversion.shtml 1 cup of un-sifted all-purpose flour is equal to 120g.

Therefore 1000 divided by 120 is 8.3 recurring (1000/120=8.3).

8.3 multiplied by 1.5 (1 1/2 teaspoons) is 12.45 , so let's round it to 12.5 (12 1/2 teaspoons or 4.167 tablespoons, rounded to 4 tablespoons), (8.3*1.5=12.45). In metric this is 45g of baking powder.

8.3 multiplied by 0.25 is 2.075, so let's round it to 2 (2 teaspoons), (8.3*0.25=2.075). In metric this is 10g if salt.

So for 1kg of flour you will need 45g baking powder (4 tablespoons) of baking powder and 10g (2 teaspoons) of salt.

Comment: +1 for metric. I've been searching for the correct ratio in grams and it has been very difficult to come by.

Comment: What is the reason salt was added?

Comment: I'm just going round the site correcting this info - UK self-**raising** flour does not contain salt. US self-**rising** flour does. UK also contains a higher %age of baking powder than the US variant.

Answer (score -2):

i use one level tsp baking powder for every one cup of plain flour

Answer (score -3):

1 cup of AP flour to 1.5 teaspoon of baking soda.